# How to import zip file which had been exported with VCPKG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, import, export, vcpkg

I used VCPKG command `.\vcpkg.exe  export cpprestsdk --7zip` to export cpprestsdk, I want to install the exported Restsdk  by other colleague, I got the message :
To use the exported libraries in CMake projects use:
    "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[...]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

how to  import the zip file by the others?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the files anywhere you like and set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` in the cmake call to the toolchain file which has been extracted.

Comment: where do I call cmake I could not find the exe ?